# /dev/disk/by-id on macOS?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filesystem, apfs, uuid

Suppose that we are doing some operations on drives using for example `diskutil`. Usually we use `/dev/diskX` to indicate which drive we are working on, but the number X could change next time we connect the drive to computer, so we have to look at and check the number X again and again. On Linux we have `/dev/disk/by-uuid`. How could we get this on macOS?

Answer (score 6):

That device tree doesn’t exist as a file system structure for disks (or memory) on macOS, so you’d need a third party tool to assemble an equivalent hierarchy if needed. However the file system does use UUID and you can read them with command-line tools on demand (or make an alias that constructs your tree when you issue a command of your choice or even overload `ls` with a new definition if needed.

Use the following command to obtain the UUID of a disk:

```
diskutil info diskX | awk '/Volume UUID:/ {print $5}'
```

This will give you the ***Disk / Volume UUID*** (I omitted the “Disk” portion in the awk statement for simplicity).

One you have that, you can utilize it with diskutil:

```
diskutil info XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I tested this with a WD USB external drive and it worked as expected.

#### Caveats

- **APFS drives:**  ***The synthesized drive must be referenced***.  Example:  `/dev/disk5` is the physical drive and `/dev/disk6` would be the synthesized drive.
- **HFS/HFS+ on GPT:**  ***A partition/slice must be referenced.*** Example:  `/dev/disk5s1` will give you the first partition of the drive.  Alternatively, you can obtain the partition UUIDs with the command:

  ```
  sudo gpt show diskX | awk '/GPT\ part\ -/ {print $3 "--" $7}'
  ```

  And you will get the UUIDs of the partitions by index:

  ```
  1--XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
  2--YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY
  ```
- **MS-DOS on GPT:** ***The drive or partition can be referenced.*** Examples:  `/dev/diskX` or `/dev/diskXsN`
- **MS-DOS on MBR:** ***There is no Disk UUID available***.  However, you can obtain the *Volume UUID* with the command:

  ```
  diskutil info diskXsN | awk '/Volume\ UUID:/ {print $3}'
  ```
- **HFS/HFS+ on MBR:** Same as MS-DOS on MBR.

Comment: Does the UUID for a volume persist through unmount/mont like its name?

Comment: @WGroleau - yes.  I tested it on multiple partition types and formats.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `/dev/disk/by-uuid` folder structure in macOS.

macOS uses UUIDs for internal structures within a physical disk, such as a partition (equatable to an APFS container or HFS+ partition), or an APFS volume. The best you can do is to identify a physical device after connection by the structures it contains, rather than anything associated with the physical device itself.

The device specification in `diskutil` sub-commands will accept a UUID as an argument. Check `man diskutil` and search for `DEVICES` for all the accepted device identifiers.

You can retrieve the UUID for a particular container or volume by using eg. `diskutil info disk5` and grepping for the `Disk / Partition UUID`, or `Volume UUID`.

Unfortunately I don't think there's any switch to make `diskutil list` output the UUID. However, you can use `diskutil apfs list` which will also output UUIDs for APFS containers and volumes.

Answer (score 1):

```
df | grep "/dev/" | awk '{print $NF " = " $1}'
```

is one way to map the names of the volumes to their device IDs.  The name of the volume (`$NF`) will not change until a user or script changes it.  A `sed` or `perl` (etc.) regex can remove the slice ID if needed: `s:(/dev/disk\d+)s\d+:\1:`

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Ok, OpenZFS installed a daemon that does the function that is built into Linux. https://github.com/openzfsonosx/zfs/tree/master/cmd/InvariantDisks

So this solution will work if you install OpenZFS. https://openzfsonosx.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3743 which is available for Mavericks through Ventura, including Apple Silicon.

There actually is a disk-by-id in macOS! It is, however, in a different section than /dev. It is `/var/run/disk/by-id`

There are other options as well.

`/var/run/disk/by-id` - returns either media-UUID or volume-UUID for all the drives.

`/var/run/disk/by-image-path` - doesn't show anything on my Mac.

`/var/run/disk/by-path` - Drives by connection path. Very useful if you want to map drives by their USB port. Like if you are replicating a bunch of thumb drives.. It wouldn't matter which /dev/disk it was, as it would match the port.

`/var/run/disk/by-serial` - Returns the drive model-serial of drive... IE APPLE_SSD_AP1024R-0ba018e3e239beef or Portable_SSD_T5-029098654321.

If you want to use it in scripting, and want the disk transfers to be faster, then something like this may be used: `mainssd=$(readlink -f /var/run/disk/by-path/arm-io-ans@8F400000-iop-ans-nub-AppleANS3NVMeController-@1:0 | sed 's#/disk#/rdisk#')` - In this case, it will always return my internal SSD on my Mac Studio. Making it rdisk over disk makes transfers faster. See https://superuser.com/questions/631592/why-is-dev-rdisk-about-20-times-faster-than-dev-disk-in-mac-os-x

I discovered this from the scripts used by OpenZFS. https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: There is certainly no `/var/run/disk` on Ventura on Apple M1, so you need to qualify exactly what OS version you are claiming this for, and why you think this is available. Have you actually confirmed this, or is your answer just based on a reading of the OpenZFS scripts? Sounds like you are confusing what OpenZFS might provide vs what is standard for macOS APFS devices. The OP does not mention using OpenZFS at all. Note, I have not looked at the OpenZFS scripts to confirm either way, nor do I intend to.

Comment: There’s no `/var/run/disk` on Catalina running on Intel nor on FreeBSD.  Given that ZFS is native to FreeBSD, maybe you can point to the [documentation](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/basics/#dirstructure) where this exists

Comment: https://github.com/openzfsonosx/zfs hasn't been updated since Mojave, it might not even run on Ventura (or on ARM).

Comment: Ok, So it seems that OpenZFS installs a demaon that populates the /var/run/disk folder with symlinks. https://github.com/openzfsonosx/zfs/tree/master/cmd/InvariantDisks has the readme for it. @nohillside: https://openzfsonosx.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3743 has releases for m1 and Intel all the way up to Ventura. It has been running well on my Mac Studio running 13.5 (22G74)

Comment: So, OpenZFS is related to this question how, exactly?

Comment: @Allan I discovered /var/run/disk/by-id on my system, and I thought it was part of macOS, Hence my answer.. It turns out that OpenZFS installs a Daemon that preforms that function. OpenZFS can be installed on a system that doesn't have any ZFS drives, and the functionality in my answer will still work.