# Is iMac FusionDrive->dual SSD migration any different from HDD->SDD upgrade from Time Machine perspective?

Tags: time-machine, fusion-drive

I'm upgrading from FusionDrive to a regular drive (or a dual-drive setup).

Is there any difference as compared to regular HDD -> SSD upgrade *specifically in terms of* inheriting pre-upgrade set of Time Machine backups and using the same Time Machine volume for future backups incrementally?

In case it matters: post-upgrade boot drive will be a fully restored replica from FusionDrive-time backup on Time Machine.

---

In my particular case I'm on 2017 27" iMac, Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time Machine has no idea what the underlying physical or partition structure is configured as. Time Machine operates at the file system layer.

You could have a single spinning hard drive and upgrade to a dual SSD (core storage) setup or even RAID 0 or 1, Time Machine won’t care.  It’s only copying files from one location to another.

Comment: The only reason that made me doubtful is that TMUTIL consistently refers to UUID of source volume as identifier for backuped-up-from. Which leaves possibility that UUID for some reason is not retained when restoring FusionDrive-originating backup--while it is for vanilla HDD. Other than that, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Ahh, I see what you’re getting at, now.  The UUID is a way for TM to positively identify the volume as it never changes whereas the identifier we’re all familiar with (`disk1`, `disk2`, etc.) often do change. I wrote more about this in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/455206/119271)